# Is it possible to upgrade my laptop processor to an i3 or i5?

Tags: cpu, upgrade

I am using an Old Acer Aspire 3683 laptop and my Operating system is Fedora 13. My laptop configurations are as follows:

- Intel celeron M processor 430 (1.73 GHz, 533MHz, 1MB, L2 cache)
- Mobile Intel 940 GML Express chipset.

I woud like to know whether i can change my CPU and make it an intel core i3 or i5. Suppose if i can't do it, then can anyone tell me, if i do it, then what all will get effected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately not sorry.
Your socket is not compatible with the i3/i5/i7 range of processors, they use socket LGA 1156, the mobile versions of these processors use µPGA-989 (also different) and your motherboard is socket M. [Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core#Core_i3)

Your upgrade choices are: [Source](http://www.cpu-world.com/Sockets/Socket%20M%20(mPGA478MT).html)
The fastest socket M processors are Core 2 Duo Mobile T7600 and core 2 Duo Mobile T7600G. The T7600G has unlocked clock multiplier and can be overclocked, but it's very expensive and very difficult to find. 
If the T7600 / T7600G is too expensive for you then consider upgrading to slower Core 2 Duo Mobile processors. 
If your motherboard doesn't support Core 2 Duo Mobile CPUs then your best upgrade option is a Core Duo T2700.

Comment: Note that just because the socket matches doesn't mean the motherboard will support a newer processor.

Answer (score 3):

Well, an [Intel Celeron M 430](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Celeron_microprocessors#.22Yonah-1024.22_.2865_nm.29) requires an **M socket**.
Where as a mobile [i3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Core_i3_microprocessors#Mobile_processors) or [i5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Core_i5_microprocessors#Mobile_processors) will require a **µPGA-989 socket**.
The two are not compatible.

So, you would be unable to even fit either a i3 or i5 to your current motherboard, making attempting this upgrade impossible. This is without even considering if the motherboard chipset could support the suggested processor anyway.